# AngularJS Jqlite after doesn't add element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

Consider this runnable example: Why is el4 not put after el3? If I debug and print el3 it seems that el4 has disappeared. How can I put an element after another element, so that they become siblings?

EDIT: I don't want to append el3, before calling .after(). I simply have two angular.elements an I want combine them into two siblings, and the append or replace them in the directive element.

```js
angular.module('myModule', []) 


.directive('mydir', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template:'<div><b>{{myf.str}}</b>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
          
          
            var el = angular.element('<b>First </b>');
            var el2 = angular.element('<i>Second</i><br>');
            el.append(el2);
            elem.append(el);
          
          
            var el3 = angular.element('<b>Third </b>');
            var el4 = angular.element('<i>Fourth</i>');
            el3.after(el4);
            elem.append(el3);
          
            
        }
    };
}])
```

```html
<html ng-app='myModule'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<mydir></mydir>
```

Comment: Well, the `el3` is not appended yet so `el3.after(el4);` won't work. If you switch their places, it will work - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DsydFWErgapAegfLJX2J?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Vucko, but I want to add the elements together as siblings before appending or replacing.

Comment: There are various ways to do that. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Vucko, I have two angular.elements, I just want to add them together as a siblings object s. Then I just want to append the siblings object to the dom, element.append(s).

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])


.directive('mydir', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<div><b>{{myf.str}}</b>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {


        var el = angular.element('<b>First </b>');
        var el2 = angular.element('<i>Second</i><br>');
        el.append(el2);
        elem.append(el);


        var el3 = angular.element('<b>Third </b>');
        var el4 = angular.element('<i>Fourth</i>');

        elem.append(el3);
        elem.after(el4);


      }
    };
  }
])
```

```html
<html ng-app='myModule'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<mydir></mydir>
```

Comment: Thanks sylwester, but I want to add the two elements together as sibligs first, before appending them together.